# List not appending properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

If I have code to append 1 list into another:

```
nlis = [2, 4, 6, 8]
k = []
k.append(nlis)
print(k)
for i in range(4):
    nlis[i] += 1
k.append(nlis)
print(k)
```

For some reason this outputs:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8]]
[[3, 5, 7, 9], [3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

The `[2, 4, 6, 8]` becomes `[3, 5, 7, 8]`.

How can I make it so that this outputs:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: You need to append a copy of the list, not the list itself: `k.append(nlis[:])`.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: It's working properly. You append the same list to another list twice, and you increment every value in that same list

Comment: I don't want to copy my list because in my real program that will make this take 100 of lists.

Comment: When you assign to `nlis` (its elements, specifically) you're reusing its memory. You either avoid this, or copy from there.

Comment: @Nexus you can either copy your list or not copy the list and use the same list over and over again, sharing the elements. On a modern machine, you can copy 100's of lists in fractions of a second. Why do you care?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nlis = [2, 4, 6, 8]
nlis2=[]
nlis2.extend(nlis)
k = []
k.append(nlis2)
k.append(nlis)
print(k[0])
for i in range(4):
    nlis[i] += 1
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]

[[2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 5, 7, 9]]
```

Or:

```
nlis = [2, 4, 6, 8]
k = []
k.append(nlis)
print(k[0])
nlis2=nlis[:]
for i in range(4):
    nlis2[i] += 1
k.append(nlis2)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` will add whatever you put in it as a single value in your list. Instead, use `.extend()`. As in `k.append(nlis)`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the whole question

Comment: I don't wan't to use extend. I wan't each list to be separate.